# How do I back out of sudo privileges in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, sudo

Is there a command to de-elevate the user from sudo permissions after I execute a command such as `sudo pmset sleep 0` so that when I try to execute another sudo command it asks for my password again?

Currently after one sudo command it will execute any others without asking for my password. The command `exit` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo -k` will do what you want; it invalidates the sudo timestamp, effectively revoking your sudo permissions so that you will be prompted for a password again next time you use sudo.

sudo doesn't (by default at least) open another terminal, so `exit` won't help; it will just quit the shell you were already using.

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html).

Comment: I think `exit` to quit the terminal works for me on Linux, in the sense that sudo's cache is restricted to a single pseudo-tty, and the cache is somehow cleared when the pty is closed.

Comment: @sourcejedi, it works, but it also has the side effect of quitting the terminal! Which I think is more than the OP was asking for.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind, thanks. Sorry it took me 3+ years to select the best answer :/

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to do this (at least you can on Linux, it may be different on OSX) by setting the `timestamp_timeout` to 0 in `/etc/sudoers`. This is the time for which the password is remembered  . On most Linux distributions, the default is set at 15 minutes. Setting it to `0` means that `sudo` will prompt for a password *every time* it is run. To change it do the following:

- Run `sudo visudo`, this will open a `vim` session allowing you to edit `/etc/sudoers`.
- Hit <kbd>i</kbd> to enter INSERT mode
- Add this line

  ```
  Defaults        timestamp_timeout=0
  ```
- Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit INSERT mode
- Hit <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file and exit.

Now, `sudo` will always ask for a password, even if you have just given it one. If you think this is too strict, you can use a higher value, say `5` for five minutes or `0.5` for 30 seconds.

---

Comment: To be clear; this will *permanently* (with a value of 0) remove the ability of sudo to remember the password, rather than clear the memory in one instance only. I'm not sure if that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier it is up to the OP to choose a rational value for their user case. I mention that they can set it to 5mins or 30secs as well.